# The selection of the amplitude of the signal, consisting of rectangular pulses, at different frequencies

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, frequency, algorithms, digital

I already asked a similar question, but did not receive an answer and did not find a solution, I want to make another attempt to get to the bottom of the truth.

There is a signal consisting of rectangular pulses at different frequencies and other noises. The amplitude of the rectangular pulses may vary. The duration of the pulses can be either 100 μs, or vary by 150-200 pulses per 200 μs.

This is a real signal, which consists of pulses at a frequency of 1 kHz, pulses at a frequency of 1.4 kHz and other noises.
[image]

How can one distinguish the amplitude of these pulses and find out the duration? If more details, I need to find:

- The amplitude of the pulses is 1 kHz. (the pulses themselves are not important, I just need the average amplitude of each pulse)
- The pulse amplitude of 1.4 kHz. (the pulses themselves are not important, I just need the average amplitude of each pulse)
- The duration of 1 kHz impulses (the exact time is not required, I just need “yes” if the duration is 100 µs, “no” if the duration is 200 µs.)
- The duration of 1.4 kHz impulses (the exact time is not needed, I need “yes” if the duration is 100 µs, “no” if the duration is 200 µs.)

I thought that you can use two band IIR filters, for example 6 orders of magnitude at a frequency of 1 kHz and a frequency of 1.4 kHz, respectively. But after the filter, the amplitude and duration of the initial rectangular signal are lost, and I cannot calculate the initial amplitude and duration of the pulses.

I saw a device that somehow solves this problem on a simple microcontroller, when applying such a signal to the input, at the output I see the amplitudes of both signals, so I concluded that somehow it can be done programmatically. For a month I have been trying to find a solution to this problem on the Internet in both my native language and internationally, but my searches have come to nothing. Perhaps someone solved a similar problem and simply did not share the solution, or no one came across a similar task ... I re-read a lot of pages of “stackexchange” in search of a solution to the problem, but I couldn’t find the answer. I will be glad of any help in solving this problem!

Here is an attempt to simulate this signal in a matlab:

```
Fs = 100000;
t = 0:1/Fs:0.01;
F = 1.5;
f0 = 1000;
tau = 0.0001;
s = (square(2*pi*t*f0, f0*tau*100) + 1)* F/2;
s = s+randn(size(t))/50;

F2 = 2;
f02 = 1400;
tau2 = 0.0001;
s2 = (square(2*pi*t*f02, f02*tau2*100) + 1)* F2/2;
s2 = s2+randn(size(t))/50;

a=s+s2;
```

[image]

Next, I created mask “b” and tried to use circular cross correlation for verification:

```
b=0;
for i=1:10
    b(i)=1;
end
for i=11:100
    b(i)=0;
end
b=[b,b,b,b,b];

xcorr = fft(a).*conj(fft(b,length(a)));
```

At the output, I got this picture.

[image]

Here is the result of circular cross correlation with no bias of the original signal, with bias of 30:
[image]
[image]

Next, on the threshold, I find the beginning of the impulse, and did the integration over 100 μs and a dump:

```
temp=0;
i=1;
corrf=[];
for g=1:1000
   if (corr(g)>42) || (temp==1)
      temp=1;
      corrf(i)=corr(g);
      i=i+1;
    end
end
corrf=corrf(1:900);
intdump(corrf,10);
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a straightforward signal identification as was already answered previously- create a mask of the pulses and compare minimum distance to make decision - is there any further constraining information as to the rate of amplitude change from pulse to pulse or the number of pulses possible? This would further improve the performance under noise conditions

Comment: So your output looks good to me: your test signal has zero offset in time so is aligned with your mask, which has a maximum correlation in the first bin as expected (or so it appears from the picture). The other peaks are the positions in time where a partial number of pulses overlap with your mask (as to be expected) but the largest occurs where they all overlap. Try shifting your test signal to be later in time so that you can see how your cross correlation changes accordingly, and see how you can predict where the signals are from your cross correlation alone.

Comment: (Also try making your 1.4 KHz mask to confirm you can locate either pulse separately as you change the time offset of each.)  If the pulses were always present, as you show then there is no reason to make your mask longer than 5 ms.

Comment: Well, I’ll try to experiment with this simulation of the signal. But I still do not fully understand how "xcorr = fft (a). * Conj (fft (b, length (a)))" does this formula work?

Comment: multiplication in frequency is convolution in time. Complex conjugation in frequency is time reversal in time. Convolution is Correlation of the time reversed signal, so the complex conjugate multiplication in the frequency domain is the correlation in the time domain. If done with FFT, FFT are periodic in frequency so the result in this case is a circular correlation in time. You can do correlation in time as I described to get the same result and you may want to confirm that for yourself.

Comment: @Dan Boschen I published the results of circular cross correlation when a 1kHz signal is offset by 30, 50, 80. Did I do everything right? Is that what I should be seeing?

Comment: No it is not what you should be seeing, the strong harmonic should be shifting. Can you post the mask and the test signal that you used in each case? The mask should be the same for all but the test signal should be the different shifted  one for each.

Comment: I updated the question and posted there: source signal, mask and result xcorr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is what I believe to be an optimized approach for performance in the presence of additive white noise when no other information is known about quantity of pulses or their amplitude distributions, beyond that they are 100 or 200 us long rectangular pulses and repeat at the 1KHz and 1.4KHz rates. This can be even further improved if any other further information is known (including learning from the data to see if anything else about the waveform is repetitive and therefore can be predicted once identified).

Note that the composite waveform consisting of the two pulse types combined  (pulse type meaning 1KHz and 1.4KHz pulses) repeats every 5 ms.

Create a mask to establish the timing of the pulse types. If the starting time between the two pulses is fixed and known then you can create a single reference waveform that is 0 everywhere except where a pulse could be located, and 1 in those positions using 100 us assumed durations. The longer the mask the better the result up to the maximum expected duration of a burst of pulses but keep it in 5 ms durations to take advantage of the cyclical property for using circular cross correlation.

If the 100 and 200 us pulses are equiprobable then in would actually be slightly better to use 200 us pulses in the mask (the break-even is when the ratio of 200 us pulses to 100 us pulses is $\sqrt{2}$, since 200 us masks would have 3 dB more noise which is offset by the signal increase if the mask allows the accumulation of $\sqrt{2}$ more pulses.)

Perform a circular cross correlation of the mask with a capture of the data. The result will have cyclical peaks showing the starting position of the 5ms composite pattern.

The circular cross correlation is given by the following which could be used as a quick test of the procedure:

$$XCORR = ifft(fft(b)conj(fft(a))$$

Where fft(a) is the fft of your mask and fft(b) is the fft of your data.

Here is a very simple example of that to demonstrate how this is done properly and the expected result since the OP is having trouble with this step:

```
>> mask = [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0];
>> // create three cases of test data for example
>> dataAlligned = mask;
>> dataShiftOne = circshift(mask,1,2);
>> dataShiftTwo = circshift(mask,2,2);
```

Thus each would be:

mask = [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0];

dataAlligned = [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0];

dataShiftOne = [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0];

dataShiftTwo = [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0];

The circular cross correlation is done for each case above as:

```
>> corr = @(data,mask) ifft(fft(data).*conj(fft(mask)));
```

Below shows the result of this for each case:

```
>> corr(dataAllgined, mask)
ans = 
   3   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0
>> corr(dataShiftOne, mask)
ans =
   0   3  -0   0   0   0   3  -0   0   0   0   3  -0   0   0
>> corr(dataShiftTwo, mask)
ans = 
   0   0   3   0  -0   0   0   3   0  -0   0   0   3   0  -0
```

Given the sparse nature of the mask, the implementation for the circular cross correlation would likely be more efficient in the time domain by repeated multiply and sums at all circular rotations of the mask. Given the mask only has values of 0 and 1 this would be quite simple to compute even in a microcontroller, as the multiply operation would just be a selection of which samples to sum.

If the starting delay between the two pulse types is not known, then do the above with two masks; one for the 1KHz pulses and one for the 1.4KHz pulses.

Once timing is established for the above techniques, then we know when a pulse of each type should appear if a pulse is to be present in that interval. So at this point to detect each pulse use an integrate and dump that would integrate over 100us in two successive durations at all the expected start times. (This can be implemented with a moving average filter that has a width equal to the pulse duration, and taking the samples of the moving average output at each expected end of pulse location.)  A decision metric is established using a noise optimized threshold on the integrate and dump output to decide pulse present=1 or pulse not present = 0. The use of two successive durations is to determine if the pulse was 100us long or 200 is long (decoding 1,1 or 1,0 for that interval).

The magnitude of each pulse is the magnitude of the integrate and dump output scaled by the number of samples—- keep a running average of the detected magnitude for each pulse type and adjust the threshold based on the averaged magnitude to optimize the decision for pulse present or not present.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try to explain in more detail:
1) I do not know the exact start time of 1 kHz and 1.4 kHz pulses. That is, impulses always run (endlessly), and I can start processing at any moment.

Comment: 2) As for the impulses of 200 μs, I will try to explain this:
If 1kHz: 100-900-100-900-100-900 ... 200-800-200-800-200-800 (and so on 200 packs) ... 100-900-100-900-100-900. All values are in micro seconds.
If 1.4kHz: 100-614-100-614-100-614 ... 200-514-200-514-200-514 (and so on 200 packs) ... 100-614-100-614-100-614. All values are in micro seconds.
3) In this case, as it was in the waveform above, the pulses can partially or completely overlap each other.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you suggest passing pulses through a 5ms mask. But here a problem arises, because I do not know the exact time of the start of the impulse, and I also do not understand what to do at the moment of partial or complete overlap of the impulses.

Comment: For example, I have a sampling frequency of 100kHz. I have two masks for 1 kHz this is an array of 500 samples (5ms) (1-10..0-90 ... 1-10..0-90 ... 1-10..0-90 ... 1 -10..0-90), where ten 1, then ninety 0 and so five times. For 1.4kHz, this is an array of 355 samples (1-10..0-61 ... 1-10..0-61 ... 1-10..0-61 ... 1-10..0-61 ... 1-10..0-61), where ten 1, then sixty one 0, and so five times. Next, you need to perform a "rolling circular correlation." Did I understand this part correctly?

Comment: I wanted to try to simulate these signals in a Matlab first. While I can’t do anything, my experience with the Matlab is very small. Can you give any real example with any signal in the Matlab?

Comment: Yes, for 1.4kHz you are absolutely right! These are signals from different transmitters received by one receiver. Yes, your advice was very helpful to me, thank you very much. I will try to understand matlab to simulate this solution.

Comment: Many thanks! As I get something I will publish the results, maybe they will help someone else. But I don’t understand a bit how to implement this on the microcontroller ... I have a continuously running signal from the ADC with a sampling frequency of 100 kHz and a mask as I wrote above. Am I typing an array of values with an ADC and doing the multiplication of each element by each element of the mask array?

Comment: That is, I fill the array with data from the ADC, as soon as there are 500 values, I multiply each element of the array by each element of the mask. Ideally, if the phase matches, I get 5 peaks of the signal. If the phase does not match, then I shift the ADC array by 1 and do the same until I see 5 signal peaks. But when the signals are partially / completely superimposed, I will get the wrong amplitude at this peak. And will I calculate the total amplitude as the average of these 5 peaks? Do I understand everything correctly?

Comment: If you want to do the same correlation approach in the time domain (which would be more appropriate for a microcontoller) then in this case the mask tells you which of the 500 samples you select to be summed, you select and sum those samples and then plot this result (would be the same as the first bin in your IFFT). You then circularly shift your data (or the mask) and repeat to plot the next bin. You do this for all bins and you are at the same point as the result for the IFFT and proceed the same way from there.

Comment: The amplitude will change, but not so dramatically that there was 0.5V on one pulse, and 2.5V on the next. Rather, it will be so on a single pulse 0.5V, then 0.51V, 0.52V and so on up to 2.5V. I meant that the amplitude will change, but very smoothly. Without any sharp jumps.
I thought to use the FFT approach and further “integration and reset” is too expensive and difficult for the microcontroller.

Comment: Excuse me, but I still do not fully understand how you propose to implement this algorithm on a microcontroller. Perhaps this is due to a language barrier or lack of my knowledge ... What is a "bin"? Can you describe it differently?

Comment: With a frequency of 100 kHz, I receive data from the ADC and type in an array of 500 values “x”. As soon as the array is full, I multiply each element of this array by each element of the mask array “y” (which consists of 1-10 ... 0-90 and so on) and get a new array “z”. An array can be filled in different ways, as the phase lies. But what to do next? How to find the condition that I got into the signal phase? To what condition do I need to shift the array or mask to get into the signal phase?

Comment: The FFT approach is only to validate/simulate quickly your overall approach but once that works you would do the time domain approach as I suggested in the microcontroller--where you simply add up the values that are underneith your mask.

Comment: I tried mixing the signal and posted the results. I also tried a 1.4kHz mask.

Comment: In order to proceed with the rest of it, you need the best estimate for the actual start time of each pulse type. That's what this IFFT operation is giving you.

Comment: So should I shift a mask (not a signal)? P.S. Sorry, l must go now. I will try it tomorrow and share here.

Comment: I published the result of circular cross correlation when a 1kHz signal is offset by 30, 50, 80, while the 1.4kHz signal remains as it is. I can’t post the signals themselves (I can’t add more than 8 pictures), so I published only the results.

Comment: I updated my answer for you. Also I am deleting all my previous comments that are no longer contributing since this comment thread is so long.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll take a look and maybe understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: I understood my mistake. Those pictures that I attached to you before, followed from this formula: xcorr = fft (a). * Conj (fft (b, length (a))); Where the signal length was 1000 and the mask length was 500.
If I use this formula corr = ifft (fft (a). * Conj (fft (b))); Where the signal is 1000 long and the mask 1000 is long, the correct result is obtained and I really see the displacement, as you said!

Comment: I do not understand why I did not succeed with this formula: xcorr = fft (a). * Conj (fft (b, length (a))); ? When the signal consisted of 1000 samples, and the mask of 500 ... But now I can clearly see how the offset of the original signal affects!

Comment: You result looks good and from this you can estimate the offset (be sure you see how to extract the exact offset). You would have another mask to extract the starting position of the other pulse type. With that offset prove to yourself that you understand how to do the integrate and dump to estimate the pulses. Then you can map that process to what you would do in a microcontroller by making the shift mask and add correlation match the FFT approach.

Comment: I experimented and saw that by the value of the maximum burst I can approximately calculate the initial amplitude of the signal: Initial Amplitude = Maximum Impulse / 100-0.36. That is, I can just look for the maximums and calculate the amplitude of the initial pulses from them. If I increase the pulse duration from 100 μs to 200 μs, while leaving the mask unchanged, then I can still see how the pulse duration changes after conversion. So I can just set a threshold above which I will count pulses and find the amplitude and duration.Am I right?

Comment: If you are referring to the correlation output then no, that would not be robust in isolating when pulses are not present and what individual pulses are doing. Once you have timing from the correlation process you then do integrate and dumps (only at the known pulse start locations and integrate over 100us and dump, twice to determine if it was 100us or 200us long. The magnitude of that would be proportional to the pulse magnitude. I explained this further in my answer, did you understand that part of the process and what to do now?

Comment: I see real data so far only on the oscilloscope, while there is no recording capability. Therefore, I want to understand the simulation for now. But in the future I plan to record a real signal and do the same thing on it already.

Comment: You can’t save the data on the oscilloscope and import to Matlab?

Comment: No, my oscilloscope cannot do this, I need to write a separate program for recording data, and I will write it in the next! But first, I wanted to deal with the simulation. I did not fully understand the part about "integrate and dumps", could you explain in more detail?

Comment: In the future, I will definitely record the real signal and try everything that I did on the simulation. I will share the results here. Now I want to understand how to do "integration and dump". Is integration a finding of an area that is under an integrable function? And what is a "dump"? In my language, it has many meanings, can you explain it differently?

Comment: Sorry to ask you constantly. I really try to understand how it works. You really help me with this! Thank you very much!

Comment: As I understand it, I must now take some kind of threshold and when crossing this threshold calculate the area (integrate)? And so with every impulse?

Comment: From the correlation you did, you now know the specific time that each pulse should start: at those times specifically accumulate (integrate) the waveform for 100us and then store the final value at the end of the integration time and reset the accumulator to 0 (that is “dump”: dump the value, reset accumulator- this is I&D). Since you pulses can be 100 or 200 us wide, immediately repeat after clearing the first time for another 100 us and dump that result, then wait for the next pulse start at the next 1ms interval (if 1 KHz pulses) and repeat the double I&D.

Comment: From each I&D result set a threshold to decide if a pulse was present or not for that value and decode accordingly: 1 0   --   1 0   --    1 1  --      1 0  ---        (1 1 means a 200 us pulse and 1 0 is a 100 us pulse, 0 0 would be no pulse and 0 1 would be erroneous as that can't occur.

Comment: I added the code and the picture as I do the integration and dump, after I found the beginning of the signal. Am I doing right? How to determine exactly the time when the impulse began? Set threshold?

Comment: No it doesn't look right as you only integrate and dump at the times where you know a pulse could occur- your plot shows values at all times. However it is useful to see if you established the timing correct-- given your second pulse is larger than the other times where there are no pulse shows that you are starting the integrate and dump a little too early, so you are getting a partial overlap during the two integrates that you do in those locations.

Comment: To determine the start of the pulses, use the max of the correlation, not a threshold.  The max occurs when your mask is in perfect alignment with our pulses--so the start of a pulse in your mask will be the start of the integrate and dump that you want with the shift where the correlation is at its max value.

Comment: It will be simplest to just implement the integrate and dump function as a moving average (over a 100 us pulse width so a 10 sample moving average) and then from the timing that you derive from the longer mask correlation you can select the right samples from the moving average output (this will be the same result as what I described with the integrate and dump that you only do at the pulse locations. In this case the correct sample time will be at the expected end of the pulse (the moving average will have triangle ramps out and these locations will be at the peak of those triangles)

Comment: moving average over 10 samples in matlab is output = filter([1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1],1, input);

Comment: That is, after circular cross-correlation, I find the maximum for one impulse, I take 10 samples after the maximum and do a moving average? Or do I need to pass the entire XCORR through a moving average?
And how can I find the amplitude and duration? By the original signal?

Comment: The XCORR is Just to find the timing of when to sample. Your original data goes through the moving average. Please review the results for the XCORR for each of the test cases you did and it should be clear to you how you can use that to predict the correct locations to sample the moving average result

Comment: That is, first pass the signal through the "moving average", and then perform circular cross correlation? I understand correctly?
Now I realized that to a certain extent it is possible to separate one signal from another using circular cross correlation, but I do not understand how to further distinguish the amplitude and duration. I realized that for the microcontroller I can use:
for k = 1: length (b)
     c (k) = a * b ';
     b = [b (end), b (1: end-1)];
end
Where “a” is the signal, and “b” is the mask.

Comment: But how to proceed further? I'm confused. How can I get the amplitude and duration of pulses of a certain frequency?

Comment: Sorry that you don’t see it yet—- I think we’re beyond the level of help appropriate for this forum. Please email me at boschen@loglin.com and we can see if I can help you further offline.

Comment: Sorry. OK, I will write to you.