# Finding events in a signal given its number

Tags: template-matching

I have a signal with14 events

[image]

of 2 types:

- type 1: the 4th and the 10th peak
- type 2: the rest of the peaks

I would like a function in which the input is the number of events of each type  and the output should be the timing and the type of each event.

Does anyone knows any function that performs this (maybe some machine learning algorith). I use R, but I can also use python.

I have signals with events of different shapes (the plot is just one example). I would like to have a function that works independently of the shape of the events so I do not need to provide information about the specific shapes that I have for a given signal.

Comment: This looks like you could even write this down in English as "an event is a positive jump, where the next sample is more than 3 larger than the previous one; it's a type 1 if the sample after..." and just write this down as python. Where's your specific problem in implementing that?

Comment: I would like a function that works independently of the shape of the events (edited the question to make this clear).

Comment: aha. Have you heard of *correlation*? That's probably a term worth understanding here.

Comment: This post may help you? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62956/the-selection-of-the-amplitude-of-the-signal-consisting-of-rectangular-pulses/62957#62957